# method to get Webelement with highest value from list of webelements

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to write a method that would return a **WebElement** of a row with highest value. I have a list

```
List<Rows> rows = getNames();
```

then I need to get values from some columns. Which is OK, but I dont know how to get the highest one, and return THAT WebElement with that value. I know how to get highest int, but then return its webelement?
example

```
List<WebElement> columnValus = null;
for (int i=0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
columnValus.add(rows.get(i).getColumnValue("nameOfTheColumn")) //it will return its value as string, but can be converted to int
}
```

that's where I got stuck

Comment: The easiest solution is: set first element as highest outside loop. Then iterate over array in the loop and compare value of current element with highest one (I assume, you know how to access this value). If value is higher, then assign current element to the highest element. After loop return the highest element.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `rows` is a list of `WebElements`. I also assume there is a method to get a value from `WebElement` what returns an `int` value.
If so, the code can be something like this:

```
public WebElement getMaxRow(){
    WebElement result;
    int maxVal = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(WebElement row : rows){
        if(row.getValue()>maxVal){
            result = row;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```